# Initializing a dictionary with zeroes

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to track seen elements, from a big array, using a dict.
Is there a way to force a dictionary object to be integer type and set to zero by default upon initialization?

I have done this with a very clunky codes and two loops.

Here is what I do now:

```
fl = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]
seenit = {}

for val in fl:
    seenit[val] = 0

for val in fl:
    seenit[val] = seenit[val] + 1
```

Comment: *"force a dictionary ...  set to zero by default upon initialization"* -- [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: There's `seenit  = dict.fromkeys(fl, 0)` to replace the first loop, but the current answers provide better solutions for replacing both loops at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, just use [`collections.defaultdict([default_factory[, ...]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

fl = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]

seenit = defaultdict(int)

for val in fl:
    seenit[val] += 1

print(fl)
# Output
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})

print(dict(seenit))
# Output
{0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

In addition, if you don't like to import `collections` you can use [`dict.get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
fl = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]

seenit = {}

for val in fl:
    seenit[val] = seenit.get(val, 0) + 1

print(seenit)
# Output
{0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

Also, if you only want to solve the problem and don't mind to use *exactly* dictionaries you may use [`collection.counter([iterable-or-mapping])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

fl = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]

seenit = Counter(f)

print(seenit)
# Output
Counter({1: 3, 0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})

print(dict(seenit))
# Output
{0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

Both `collection.defaultdict` and `collection.Counter` can be read as `dictionary[key]` and supports the usage of `.keys()`, `.values()`, `.items()`, etc. Basically they are a subclass of a common dictionary.

If you want to talk about performance I checked with [`timeit.timeit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) the creation of the dictionary and the loop for a million of executions:

- `collection.defaultdic`: 2.160868141 seconds
- `dict.get`: 1.3540439499999999 seconds
- `collection.Counter`: 4.700308418999999 seconds

`collection.Counter` may be easier, but much slower.

Comment: Thanks. This newbie appreciates all the help. I like the defaultdic solution and will go with this.

Comment: @giggleusa if you find this or another answer useful you should consider accepting the answer as the correct one (pressing the gray mark under the downvote button). You would receive 2 reputation for accepting one. Otherwise, your question will stay *unanswered*.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4])
```

Output:

```
Counter({1: 3, 0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
```

You can then address it like a dictionary:

```
>>> Counter({1: 3, 0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})[1]
3
>>> Counter({1: 3, 0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})[0]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `val in seenit` is a bit faster than `.get()`:

```
seenit   = dict()
for val in fl:
    if val in seenit :
        seenit[val] += 1
    else:
        seenit[val] = 1
```

*For larger lists, Counter will eventually outperform all other approaches. and `defaultdict` is going to be faster than using `.get()` or `val in seenit`.*